# Why does the Tekkit (New) Buildcraft Redstone Engine get overheated in the nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-tekkit

When I place a Tekkit (New) Buildcraft Redstone Engine in the nether it gets overheated, I would like to know why?

I made pump and 4 redstone engines but the engines are turning from green to orange really fast, why is that? I want to power the pump without coming back to the nether.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Buildcraft, Redstone Engines can't overheat. Turning green and orange and speeding up is good, this means they're getting to operating temperature. Only if they turn red and stop, that means you've got a problem, but, as answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59389/can-buildcrafts-redstone-engines-explode), Redstone Engines don't do that.